# Jackson: How to change the indentation of the colon in the JSON outpout?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have JSON ouput that has 1 whitespace on the left side of the colons.
I need to eliminate that whitespace on the left side.

Below is my output.
Below that is the code that produces it.

I need to leave everything else in the output as it is, so I can't get rid of pretty printing or indenting the braces.

```
[
    {
        "satelliteId" : 1000,
        "severity" : "RED HIGH",
        "component" : "TSTAT",
        "timestamp" : "2018-01-01T23:01:38.001Z"
    },
    {
        "satelliteId" : 1000,
        "severity" : "RED LOW",
        "component" : "BATT",
        "timestamp" : "2018-01-01T23:01:09.521Z"
    }
]
```

**code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class FormatAlerts {
    List<Message> alerts = new ArrayList<>();

    public FormatAlerts(List<Message>alerts){
        this.alerts = alerts;
    }

    public String formatAlerts(){

        String formattedAlerts = null;
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayNode arrayNode = om.createArrayNode();

        // Create a "Pretty Printer" that will indent brackets and braces more
        String indent = String.format("%-4s","");
        DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter indenter = new DefaultIndenter(indent, DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF);
        DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
        printer.indentObjectsWith(indenter);
        printer.indentArraysWith(indenter);


        try {
            for (Message m : alerts) {
                // Format the time 
                Instant t = Instant.ofEpochMilli(m.getEpochTime());
                m.setTimestamp(t.toString());

                //Format the alert as Json
                String alert = om.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(m);
                //String alert = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(m);
                ObjectNode obj = om.readValue(alert, ObjectNode.class);          
                arrayNode.add(obj);
                formattedAlerts = om.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(arrayNode);
                //formattedAlerts = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(arrayNode);
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            jpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedAlerts;
    }
}
```

Comment: cleanJsonString = dirtyJsonString.replace(“ : ”, “: “);

Comment: @JohnWilliams I hope you are joking? Never use a regex on a JSON string

Comment: Whitespace isn't significant in that location, as far as JSON parsers are concerned, and your output is perfectly readable. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @JohnWilliams I need to do it the right way, and not the wrong way with patching the results.  Thanks for the thought.

Comment: @tgdavies the people I am making this for are unforgiving.  If it was just for me I would have left the ouput  as a linear string.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but you can create your own pretty printer class which uses a different separator:

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter() {
            @Override
            public DefaultPrettyPrinter createInstance() {

                return new DefaultPrettyPrinter(this);
            }

            @Override
            public DefaultPrettyPrinter withSeparators(Separators separators) {
                _separators = separators;
                _objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces = separators.getObjectFieldValueSeparator() + " ";
                return this;
            }
        };
printer = printer.withSeparators(Separators.createDefaultInstance());
```

This replaces the value in `_objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces` with  `": "` instead of the usual `" : "`.

The printer returned by `createInstance` will never be used, but `createInstance` still needs to be overridden.